# Como alterar item em um índice de um ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou com dificuldade nesse exercício de array:

> a) Crie a classe BlocoDeNotas que possui como atributo um
>   `ArrayList<String>` chamado notas. Crie métodos para inserir, remover e
>   buscar notas. Crie um método que imprima todas as notas.
>
> b) Crie a classe AppBloco, com um método main, e um menu que
>       1) Insira uma nota,
>       2) Remova uma nota,
>       3) Altere uma nota,
>       4) Listar todas as notas e
>       5) Saia do sistema.

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class BlocoDeNotas{

  private ArrayList<String> notas = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void inserirNota (String nota){
   notas.add(nota);
  }


  public int buscarNota (String nota){
   for(int i=0; i < notas.size(); i++){
      if(notas.get(i).equals(nota))
        return i;            
   }
   return -1;  
  }
  public boolean removerNota(String nota){
   int posicao = buscarNota(nota);
   if (posicao >= 0){
      notas.remove(posicao);
      return true;
   } 
   return false;
  }

  public void listarNotas(){
   for (String minhaNota:notas){
      System.out.println(minhaNota);
   }

  } 


}
```

Está faltando fazer o método para alterar uma nota, pedido no enunciado. Como que eu faço isso?

Answer (score 3):

Crie um método que receba a nova nota e o índice que esta nova nota irá substituir, e utilize o método [`ArrayList.set(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) para fazer a troca:

```
public void alterarNota(int indice, int novaNota){

    if(indice >= 0 && indice < notas.size()){

        notas.set(indice, novaNota);
    } 
}
```

A condicional é necessária para evitar que estoure `ArrayIndexOfBoundException` por acesso a índices inexistentes da lista.